# ¿Cómo hacer un bucle de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-webdriver

Tengo una lista de placas vehiculares en excel, tengo que buscar si tienen infracciones de tránsito y generar un reporte. Mi pregunta es cómo hacer que me realice la búsqueda de cada una de las placas de la lista. Sé que los loops son básicos, pero no logro poder hacerlo.

Este es mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

df = (pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Dais.facturacion/Desktop/mis macros/prueba.xlsx'))
print (df)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://data.finanzas.cdmx.gob.mx/consulta_adeudos')

for i in df.index:
    entry=df.loc[1]
elem = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputPlaca')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys(entry["placa"] + Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(15)
browser.quit()
```

este es parte del df:
placa
0    J34AER
1    L87AES
2    598WJG
3    992VWV
4     5A1KG
5     5A2KG
6     9641K
7    743VLJ
8    428VLJ
9    828VLJ
10   603VLJ

Comment: Podrias dejar un fragmento de tu dataframe?

Comment: Listo, edité la publicacion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ¡Buen día!

Según tu codigo puedo notar que lo que tratas de hacer es verificar el estado de una placa en una pagina nacional, hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar en tu pequeño script:

1. Esta de mas poner parantesis al momento de cargar tu `df` y no deberias dejar espacios al momento de realizar una impresión por consola.
2. Es innecesario que extraigas el indice y despues busques el dato en ese indicé, lo corrrecto seria iterar sobre la columna que me imagino que lleva por nombre "placas"
3. Si deseas verificar elemento por elemento se debe pasar el nombre de la placa que se esta recorriendo en el bucle y no una vector ya que este ultimo causaria errores.
   Dicho esto el codigo quedaria así:

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["placas"]= [ "J34AER" , "L87AES ", "598WJG" ," 992VWV ", "5A1KG" , "5A2KG" , "9641K" , "743VLJ" ,"428VLJ", "828VLJ" ," 603VLJ"]


for i in df["placas"]:
  elem = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'inputPlaca')  # Find the search box
  elem.send_keys(i + Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(15)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que necesitaba, se que tengo muchos errores estoy principiando en el tema python jeje, el codigo esta bien el problema que tengo al ejecutar es que en el searchbox no borra el dato anterior y la siguiente busqueda se escribe junto a la anterior y asi, que comando puedo usar para que en cada busqueda limpie el searchbox? gracias.

Comment: Selenium tiene un metodo llamada clear() el cual te servira para borrar lo que se encuentre en un input pasate por su documentacion en el siguiente enlace [Documentacion](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: @Charlie Si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas [Lectura recomendada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Pudiste lograrlo?

Comment: Gracias, si pude lograrlo, resolviste muy bien mi duda.